# Help evaluating an interesting series.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to evaluate the sum
$$
s = 1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}\cdots.
$$

The hint I was given was $\frac{1}{2n+1} = \int_0^1 x^{2n} \, dx$. I'm familiar with the trick of writing the $n$th term of series with a definite integral and then interchanging the order of integral and sum, but the signs on the terms are making this difficult for me. If this were a normal alternating series, we could do something like
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{2n+1} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1 (-1)^n x^{2n} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x^2)^{n}\right)dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx = \arctan(1)-\arctan(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}

I can't however seem to proceed with the strange alternating series. I know that $(-1)^{(n^2+n+2)/2}$ gives the right pattern of $++--++--\dots$, but that doesn't combine well with the $x^{2n}$ term in the integrand after exchanging sum and integral.

Any thoughts?

Edit: If I use the imaginary unit $i$, then I can write a related sum
$$
\tilde{s} = 1+\frac{1}{3}i-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}i+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}\cdots.
$$
Using the above trick gives
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(i)^{n}\frac{1}{2n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(i)^nx^{2n}dx = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(ix^2)^n =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-ix^2}dx
$$
Which I imagine I can do with some type of partial fraction decomposition.

My hope is that from this new sum I can recover my old sum by adding real and imaginary parts. My only concern is that this would essentially be a rearrangement of the series (adding the even indexed terms together and then the odd indexed terms separately) and this series doesn't converge absolutely so I'm worried that this isn't rigorously justified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$  \left( 1+x^2 - x^4 - x^6 \right)  \left(1 + x^8 + x^{16} + x^{24}  + x^{32} + x^{40} + x^{48} \cdots  \right) $$
$$   \frac{1+x^2-x^4-x^6}{1-x^8} =   \frac{(1-x^4)(1+x^2)}{(1-x^4)(1 + x^4)} = \frac{1+x^2}{1 + x^4}$$
which can be integrated by partial fractions; note that
$$ x^4 + 1 = \left(x^2 - x\sqrt 2 + 1 \right)  \left(x^2 + x \sqrt 2 + 1 \right) $$

We are looking for
$$  \int \frac{1}{1+(x \sqrt 2 + 1)^2}  + \frac{1}{1+(x \sqrt 2 - 1)^2} dx $$

Comment: Very clever! I really like how well this generalizes to other forms of “alternating”.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
You can write your series as
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
\pars{{1 \over 4n + 1} + {1 \over 4n + 3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{4n} + x^{4n + 2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + x^{2}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-x^{4}}^{n}\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + x^{2}}{1 \over 1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{4} + x^{2} - x^{6} \over
1 - x^{8}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{-7/8} - x^{-3/8} + x^{-5/8} - x^{-1/8}\,\, \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\bracks{-\Psi\pars{1 \over 8} +
\Psi\pars{5 \over 8} - \Psi\pars{3 \over 8} + \Psi\pars{7 \over 8}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\braces{%
\bracks{\Psi\pars{7 \over 8} - \Psi\pars{1 \over 8}} +
\bracks{\Psi\pars{5 \over 8} - \Psi\pars{3 \over 8}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 8}\ \underbrace{\bracks{\pi\cot\pars{\pi \over 8} + \pi\cot\pars{3\pi \over 8}}}_{\ds{2\pi\root{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{2} \over 4}\,\pi} \approx 1.1107 \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

From your answer,
$$ \tilde{s}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-ix^2}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx+i\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx $$
and then you can obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
s&=&\Re(\tilde{s})+\Im(\tilde{s})\\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1 + x^{2}}{1 + x^{4}}\,d x\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1 + x^{2}}{1 + x^{4}}\,d x\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1 + \frac1{x^{2}}}{x^2 + \frac{1}{x^{2}}}\,d x\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x - \frac{1}{x})^2+2}\,d (x-\frac1x)\\
&=&\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2}dx\\
&=&\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what makes the rearrangement valid? Calculating $s$ as the sum of real and imaginary parts of our new series is essentially rearranging the series so that we're adding $1-1/5+1/9-1/13+\cdots$ to the series $1/3-1/7+1/11-1/15+\cdots$. I wanted to use the dominated convergence theorem, but $1/(1-x^2)$ isn't integrable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Where is $\frac1{1-x^2}$ from?

Comment: I'm dominating the sequence of functions $f_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(ix^{2})^n$ by the function $$F = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |ix^2|^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^2 = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ to try and use the dominated convergence theorem, but the dominating function isn't integrable. I'm just wondering how you justified the rearrangement

Comment: We can't use DCT for this as you mentioned that $\frac1{1-x^2}$ is not integrable in $[0,11]$.

Comment: right. I see that we can't use DCT (at least with that function). How did you justify the rearrangement?

Comment: Note
\begin{eqnarray}
s&=&\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bigg[
\pars{{1 \over 8n + 1} + {1 \over 8n + 3}}-\pars{{1 \over 8n + 5} + {1 \over 8n + 7}}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac1{8n+5}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{8n+3}-\frac1{8n+7}\bigg)\bigg]\\
&=&\bigg(1-\frac15+\frac19-\frac1{14}+\cdots\bigg)+\bigg(\frac13-\frac17+\frac1{11}-\frac1{15}+\cdots\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}
which verifies the rearrangement of the sum.